# Unable to open sideBar with SWRevealViewController and TabBarController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController with TabBarController in swift.
This is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pqjv2skdafzqgoj/TabBar_SideBar.zip?dl=0) of my sample project. When I am clicking on menu button it is not showing me the side menu. Anyone Can suggest me what am I missing in my project??
Here is the image of storyboard. [image: storyboard image]

Here is the code which I have written in viewController and viewController1(tab1 and tab2).

```
if self.revealViewController() != nil {
      menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
      menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
```

Please Help me. I am really not getting this thing. I have also added link of sample project.

Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

May try this

```
self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(.Left, animated: true)
menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addGestureRecognizer(revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
```

Comment: No.. This didn't work.. Did you check my sample project?

Comment: Did You Find any problem with my code?? I think there is problem in arrangement of  storyboard.. but I don't get that.. Please check it and help me.. @  Ro22e0